# The disc of convergence of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n}f_nz^n$ be a power series. Define R as the supremum of all values of $x\geq 0$ such that ${f_nx^n}$ is bounded. Then, for $|z|<R$, the sequence $f_nz^n$ tends geometrically to $0$; hence $f(z)$ is convergent.

Can anybody help me understand the above argument? What does it mean that $f(z)$ tends "geometrically" to $0$, and why does it imply $f(z)$ is convergent?

Thanks!

Comment: "Geometrically" is alluding to a limit comparison test (or similar) with a geometric series which is known to converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $|f_n z^n|$ is bounded by $C$ and $|w|<|z|$ then
$$
|f_n w^n| < |f_n| |z|^n \frac{|w|^n}{|z|^n} \leq C \left| \frac{w}{z} \right|^{n}
$$
The sum of the final term converges, and so by the comparison test, does the first one.